# ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE in spring @Query with posrgres as the database

Tags: reactjs, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I try make select and show it in datatable in react in spring using posgress as database and i using @query and i got this error near where
i got error 500
this is my code

```
@Query(value = "SELECT id, ticket AS ticket, ticket_status AS ticketStatus, sr_id AS srId, created_by AS createdBy, created_date AS createdDate, pic_sqi AS picSqi "
        + "FROM operational.break_pass_application "
        + "WHERE ticket_status NOT IN ('DRAFT', 'CANCELLED') "
        + "AND (ticket ILIKE %:search% OR ticket_status ILIKE %:search% OR sr_id ILIKE %:search%) "
        + "ORDER BY created_date DESC", nativeQuery = true)
Page<BreakPassOutput> findAllExceptDraftAndCancel(Pageable pageable, @Param("search") String search);
```

i want you to fix this code because i try evrything its look my code cannot accept where because i can show the data without where but i want show data using where